# html2canvas screenshot from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, html2canvas

I run in to unsolvable problem related to internet explorer.

The problem comes when the page is larger than 10 000px ( height ), Internet explorer 11 has a limit of 10 000 px ( height ), for canvas content. it simply will not render the content more than that.

So if the page has height more than 10 000, i would need to do a second screenshot from the bottom of the page ( body ) towards the top and then merge the two in to one or process it in any other way.

So the question is how can i force html2canvas to start from bottom of page ( body ) to top? Keep in mind i dont know what elements the page has, since it is supposed to work on any website. Is there a workaround this to force Internet Explorer to extend canvas content to more than 10 000 px. Thanks